# Use sfmc_id in single send and not in JB - Google analytics 360 integration

Tags: marketing-cloud, parameters, google-analytics

Firstly, I never integrate a MC BU with a GA360 environment.

**To my understanding of the documentation about the integration, it's works only with the emails sending from the Journey Builder.**

But I have some question about that:

1. It's true? The UTM will work only on the emails sent from the Joruneys Email Activities?
2. If yes: If I add the same parameter "sfmc_id" also in the other types of email sending GA360 ignores it? Why?
3. The standard add-on that adds (only) UTM params to all the Emails sent from MC is compatible with the GA360 integration?

Best regards and good work,
Simone

Answer (score 3, accepted):

GA360 integration with MC should not be confused with adding UTM strings to emails  to be consumed within GA

The GA360 integration only works with Journey builder in two ways

- Allows you to [create audiences](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=mc_gai_audience_activation.htm&type=5) in GA360 to use an an entry source for JB
- Allows you to view [goals/activity](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=mc_gai_google_analytics_dashboard.htm&type=5) on properties within the canvas for individual journeys and activity

If you GA360 integration MC will be default add some utm strings (including sfmc_id) to emails sent from a journey. Sends outside JB will not have these added and you will need to add them yourself.

If GA is not consuming the query string sfmc_id you need to review your GA configuration

If you simply want to manage UTM strings you should review the [WAC help docs](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=mc_wa_web_analytics_connector.htm&type=5)

Comment: Hi @EazyE, thank you for the answer, so you confirm that the GA360 integration works only in the Journeys? The UTM params configured in the GA360 integration will be added in the single send email?

Comment: I'm unsure what your question is regarding GA360, the utm string configured within GA360 is only added to JB sends since the require information from the journey. Sends using other methods would use the WAC string

Comment: OK, so MC have different configuration for JB and Single send when WAC and GA360 integrations are enable in the same account. Is it right?
But, if I add "sfmc_id" in the WAC string the GA tag in the website recognizes the contact? If the contact falls in a GA Audience sync with MC the contact come back in MC also if the click was coming from an email outside a JB?